# Why isn't rust `HashSet` return `Self` on any of its insert methods

Tags: rust, std

I'm curious about the design decision to return `bool` instead of `Option<Self>` or `Result<Self, Self>` or even `(Self, bool)`. If `HashSet` were using the `Result<Self, Self>` pattern, it would be possible to chain multiple single-item insertions like so:

```rust
set.insert(1)?
   .insert(2)?
   .insert(3)?
```

and if any of the items is present, the insertion chain stops. You get the same (but more concise) output pattern:

```rust
if set.insert(3) {
   A
} else {
   B
}
```

becomes

```rust
set.insert(3)
    .map(|| {A})
    .map_err(|| {B})
```

So I wonder if this has never occurred to the designers of the library, or was this form rejected because of some design requirement?

Comment: Rust functions that operate by side effect typically return `()` to make it clear that the modification was applied to the value passed in, and isn't confined to some return value. (Python has a similar philosophy, which is why its `list.sort` returns `None`.) The exception are methods explicitly designed for ease of chaining such as those on types implementing the builder pattern. In your code it's not obvious why you'd want to terminate the chain of inserts when an item is present. Also, are you aware that `?` doesn't just terminate the current expression, it returns from the whole function?

Answer (score 1):

The `HashSet::insert` method has a signature `pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> bool`. So it takes a &mut reference. In order to return a Self object, or Option, it would either create a new HashSet object (most sensibly by clone()), or it needs to consume ownership (using a different signature) only such that it can return itself and transfer ownership back.

The latter is senseless. The first one (clone) makes inserting anything into the HashSet needlessly ressource intensive.